# How to include goals & parameters in documentation for a maven plugin site

Tags: java, maven-2, documentation, maven-site-plugin

It appears that that you can generate a standard documentation website (like [this one](http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/)) from a Maven plugin project. I tried executing `mvn site` in a plugin project but it doesn't generate the expected documentation (a page that shows the Mojo goals, parameters, etc.). Is there some other goal that must be invoked to generate these web pages? I'm using Maven v. 2.1.0.

Comment: What do you mean by *the required documentation*. What is expected? What is the actual result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the plugin documentation (goals, params, etc.) included in the site documentation, you need to add the following to the pom.xml

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>    
  ...
</project>
```

This adds a "Project Reports" link to the site menu, which shows the Maven plugin's equivalent of Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks. This at least gets a 'Plugin Documentation' page added to the 'Project Reports' section of the site. Is there a way to automatically get this information generated as separate 'Goals' and 'Usage' pages in an 'Overview' section?? (like [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/))

Comment: Solved. I followed [this guide](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/04/how-to-auto-generate-maven-plugin-documentation/) to create the Goals link· I guess this can't be done automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, `mvn site` should at least generate an index page (and leverage the `name` and the `description`from the POM of your project) and a basic set of reports (About, Issue Tracking, Project Team, Dependencies, Project Plugins, Continuous Integration, Source Repository, Project License, Mailing Lists, Plugin Management, Project Summary).

If you want to customize the set of reports, you can configure the [Maven Project Info Reports Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/) (in the `reporting` section) to include only the reports you want:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>dependencies</report>
              <report>project-team</report>
              <report>mailing-list</report>
              <report>cim</report>
              <report>issue-tracking</report>
              <report>license</report>
              <report>scm</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

If you want to customize the site, you'll need to provide a [site descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/sitedescriptor.html) (`src/site/site.xml` by default). In that case, you'll have to include a `<menu ref="reports"/>` entry for the above reports.

If you want to [add content](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html), you'll have to provide it using one of the supported format (e.g. APT, FML, XDoc). Most of time, [APT](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/apt-format.html) is used nowadays.

Check the documentation of the [Maven Site Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't generate anything? That would be strange, it should at least build a very basic site with general information and a documentation of dependencies. `maven site`is the correct call.

For additional documentations (javadoc, test reports, etc) you need to add more elements to the build file. Have a look at the surefire plugin documentation for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

No, but your project should contain a specific structure as shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html).